# Flutter | upload large file in chunks using dio package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dio

I saw this package https://pub.dev/packages/chunked_uploader
but not clear how to upload large files in chunks. My file size is 100MB. I'm using Dio for posting the files to the server and the filePicker plugin to pick multiple files. Please help how to do this upload multiple large files in chunks. thanks in advance.

Comment: Well did you try the example?

Comment: Why would you upload a file in chunks? You did not tell. And how would the chuncks look like on the server? You also did not tell. And what exactly is it if one uploads a file in chuncks. You could tell.

Comment: yes, I try but do not understand well.

Comment: You dont have to understand the example. Just try it. Then tell us what happened and tell us what was the result on the server. Was the result that what you wanted or expected? You should tell more what you want.

Comment: I want to upload it in chunks. Because my file size is 100MB and when I upload to the server after upload noting show only this message is showing( W/Choreographer(23435): Frame time is 0.015312 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase. ). And when I upload a file which size is 25 MB it goes smooth and gives results on screen well.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you got that error message while using that example.

Comment: @Ahsan Can you please let me know if you found any luck to solve the same

Comment: no brother I don't find any possible solution. @RaghavChopra

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Can't find a way to make this package work too.

Comment: you can do it by using streams. @tomDev

Answer (score 1):

Here is good solution that can used to upload data chunked.

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart';

class ChunkedUploader {
  final Dio _dio;

  const ChunkedUploader(this._dio);

  Future<Response?> upload({
    required Stream<List<int>> fileDataStream,
    required String fileName,
    required int fileSize,
    required String path,
    Map<String, dynamic>? data,
    CancelToken? cancelToken,
    int? maxChunkSize,
    Function(double)? onUploadProgress,
    ChunkHeadersCallback? headersCallback,
    String method = 'POST',
    String fileKey = 'file',
  }) =>
      _Uploader(
        _dio,
        fileDataStream: fileDataStream,
        fileName: fileName,
        fileSize: fileSize,
        path: path,
        fileKey: fileKey,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        cancelToken: cancelToken,
        maxChunkSize: maxChunkSize,
        onUploadProgress: onUploadProgress,
        headersCallback: headersCallback,
      ).upload();

  Future<Response?> uploadUsingFilePath({
    required String filePath,
    required String fileName,
    required String path,
    Map<String, dynamic>? data,
    CancelToken? cancelToken,
    int? maxChunkSize,
    Function(double)? onUploadProgress,
    ChunkHeadersCallback? headersCallback,
    String method = 'POST',
    String fileKey = 'file',
  }) =>
      _Uploader.fromFilePath(
        _dio,
        filePath: filePath,
        fileName: fileName,
        path: path,
        fileKey: fileKey,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        cancelToken: cancelToken,
        maxChunkSize: maxChunkSize,
        onUploadProgress: onUploadProgress,
        headersCallback: headersCallback,
      ).upload();
}

class _Uploader {
  final Dio dio;
  late final int fileSize;
  late final ChunkedStreamReader<int> streamReader;
  final String fileName, path, fileKey;
  final String? method;
  final Map<String, dynamic>? data;
  final CancelToken? cancelToken;
  final Function(double)? onUploadProgress;
  late int _maxChunkSize;
  final ChunkHeadersCallback _headersCallback;

  _Uploader(
    this.dio, {
    required Stream<List<int>> fileDataStream,
    required this.fileName,
    required this.fileSize,
    required this.path,
    required this.fileKey,
    this.method,
    this.data,
    this.cancelToken,
    this.onUploadProgress,
    ChunkHeadersCallback? headersCallback,
    int? maxChunkSize,
  })  : streamReader = ChunkedStreamReader(fileDataStream),
        _maxChunkSize = min(fileSize, maxChunkSize ?? fileSize),
        _headersCallback = headersCallback ?? _defaultHeadersCallback;

  _Uploader.fromFilePath(
    this.dio, {
    required String filePath,
    required this.fileName,
    required this.path,
    required this.fileKey,
    this.method,
    this.data,
    this.cancelToken,
    this.onUploadProgress,
    ChunkHeadersCallback? headersCallback,
    int? maxChunkSize,
  }) : _headersCallback = headersCallback ?? _defaultHeadersCallback {
    final file = File(filePath);
    streamReader = ChunkedStreamReader(file.openRead());
    fileSize = file.lengthSync();
    _maxChunkSize = min(fileSize, maxChunkSize ?? fileSize);
  }

  Future<Response?> upload() async {
    try {
      Response? finalResponse;
      for (int i = 0; i < _chunksCount; i++) {
        final start = _getChunkStart(i);
        final end = _getChunkEnd(i);
        final chunkStream = _getChunkStream();
        final formData = FormData.fromMap({
          fileKey: MultipartFile(chunkStream, end - start, filename: fileName),
          if (data != null) ...data!
        });
        finalResponse = await dio.request(
          path,
          data: formData,
          cancelToken: cancelToken,
          options: Options(
            method: method,
            headers: _headersCallback(start, end, fileSize),
          ),
          onSendProgress: (current, total) =>
              _updateProgress(i, current, total),
        );
      }
      return finalResponse;
    } catch (_) {
      rethrow;
    } finally {
      streamReader.cancel();
    }
  }

  Stream<List<int>> _getChunkStream() => streamReader.readStream(_maxChunkSize);

  // Updating total upload progress
  void _updateProgress(int chunkIndex, int chunkCurrent, int chunkTotal) {
    int totalUploadedSize = (chunkIndex * _maxChunkSize) + chunkCurrent;
    double totalUploadProgress = totalUploadedSize / fileSize;
    this.onUploadProgress?.call(totalUploadProgress);
  }

  // Returning start byte offset of current chunk
  int _getChunkStart(int chunkIndex) => chunkIndex * _maxChunkSize;

  // Returning end byte offset of current chunk
  int _getChunkEnd(int chunkIndex) =>
      min((chunkIndex + 1) * _maxChunkSize, fileSize);

  // Returning chunks count based on file size and maximum chunk size
  int get _chunksCount => (fileSize / _maxChunkSize).ceil();
}

typedef ChunkHeadersCallback = Map<String, dynamic> Function(
    int start, int end, int fileSize);

// Based on RFC 7233 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-2)
final ChunkHeadersCallback _defaultHeadersCallback =
    (int start, int end, int fileSize) =>
        {'Content-Range': 'bytes $start-${end - 1}/$fileSize'};
```

Comment: This is the exact code from the package the author of this topic mentioned. Could you please provide more info, how did you made the API call?